# ffmpeg combine/concat multiple audio tracks into single audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I've downloaded the chunks parts from a stream.
Here is the manifest of the audio stream:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
## Generated with https://github.com/google/shaka-packager version v2.2.0-9e9833e-release
#EXTINF:6.037,
https://dve-streams.akamaized.net/ads-1/ns-004/MjAyMA/OQ/OA/509dfa9e-8c13-4e95-81dd-9ef4d27af7ca/audio/4d8cfd0d-26b2-4869-8c5a-488199003c95/1.aac?hdntl=exp=1638041076~acl=/*~id=77f74994-2e71-474c-93ae-fa06e58a850f~data=hdntl~hmac=e37b7c6b297c9a86c98528404edbafd448addbacc327eaf5d6117082af5b63e0
#EXTINF:5.995,
https://dve-streams.akamaized.net/ads-1/ns-004/MjAyMA/OQ/OA/509dfa9e-8c13-4e95-81dd-9ef4d27af7ca/audio/4d8cfd0d-26b2-4869-8c5a-488199003c95/2.aac?hdntl=exp=1638041076~acl=/*~id=77f74994-2e71-474c-93ae-fa06e58a850f~data=hdntl~hmac=e37b7c6b297c9a86c98528404edbafd448addbacc327eaf5d6117082af5b63e0
#EXTINF:5.995,
https://dve-streams.akamaized.net/ads-1/ns-004/MjAyMA/OQ/OA/509dfa9e-8c13-4e95-81dd-9ef4d27af7ca/audio/4d8cfd0d-26b2-4869-8c5a-488199003c95/3.aac?hdntl=exp=1638041076~acl=/*~id=77f74994-2e71-474c-93ae-fa06e58a850f~data=hdntl~hmac=e37b7c6b297c9a86c98528404edbafd448addbacc327eaf5d6117082af5b63e0
#EXTINF:5.995,
https://dve-streams.akamaized.net/ads-1/ns-004/MjAyMA/OQ/OA/509dfa9e-8c13-4e95-81dd-9ef4d27af7ca/audio/4d8cfd0d-26b2-4869-8c5a-488199003c95/4.aac?hdntl=exp=1638041076~acl=/*~id=77f74994-2e71-474c-93ae-fa06e58a850f~data=hdntl~hmac=e37b7c6b297c9a86c98528404edbafd448addbacc327eaf5d6117082af5b63e0
#EXTINF:6.016,
....
```

this manifest file contains more 1500 chunks to download, but for the example I'm posting only first of them. You have to be authenticated (somehow, not sure how authentication works) to download the audio files.

According to the shaka-packager documentation, I didn't saw an option to merge segments back to whole audio file.

`ffmpeg` provides options to merge/combine files into one. There are different issues and solutions across the internet, but some of them are working others not. I've managed to use this commands only for first for files:

`ffmpeg.exe -i .\data\1.mp3 -i .\data\2.mp3 -i .\data\3.mp3 -i .\data\4.mp3 -filter_complex 'concat' .\data\output.aac`

`ffmpeg.exe -i .\data\1.mp3 -i .\data\2.mp3 -i .\data\3.mp3 -i .\data\4.mp3 -filter_complex '[0:a] [1:a] [2:1] concat=n=1:a=1 [a]' -map '[a]' .\data\output.aac`

The above commands returns the error: `Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_concat_0`

`ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i .\data\list.txt -c copy .\data\output2.m4a`

`ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i .\data\list.txt -c:a aac -strict -2 .\data\output.m4a`

Contents of list.txt:

```
file '.\data\1.mp3'
file '.\data\2.mp3'
file '.\data\3.mp3'
file '.\data\4.mp3'
```

The last command completes the output file with following warnings in the terminal:

```
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
[aac @ 000001872b8db780] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aac @ 000001872b825740] Queue input is backward in time
[ipod @ 000001872b815d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 599894, current: 597717; changing to 599895. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[ipod @ 000001872b815d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 599895, current: 598741; changing to 599896. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[ipod @ 000001872b815d40] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 599896, current: 599765; changing to 599897. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[aac @ 000001872b8db780] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
size=     368kB time=00:00:24.87 bitrate= 121.1kbits/s speed=50.3x
video:0kB audio:362kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.443961%
[aac @ 000001872b825740] Qavg: 3319.403
```

I really not understand much of them. I already know that the downloaded segments have some problems with the duration, because 4 different players shows different duration (*only VLC player show most accurate*). Searching each warning takes me a lot of time and shows different solutions not relevant to my problem.
The final output from the last command plays the audio, but stops twice in middle for half-second and continues, which is not desired results.

I still check https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate for something that I miss. Other posts suggested to use `m4a` as an output container which solves some warnings.

Can you help me build up the correct command to contact these files without any pauses while playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading all the segments, the browser downloaded them as `.mp3` regardless of that the URL is finished with `.aac`. I've took several of them and renamed them to `.aac` with the assumption that I need to work with the correct extension. But that renaming was wrong. After a lot of try-error command executions, I realized that working with `.mp3` is OK. And should ignore that players cannot recognize the correct duration.

The final command used to merge all the chunks: `ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i .\data\list.txt .\data\output.mp3`.

.\data\list.txt contains paths to all segments:

```
file .\data\1.mp3
file .\data\2.mp3
file .\data\3.mp3
file .\data\4.mp3
...
```

I've posted more detailed information here; https://groups.google.com/g/video-downloadhelper-q-and-a/c/8V2cRB-bcK4/m/saV_Kt25BgAJ

Answer (score 0):

The segments in the manifest are AAC so you should download them to .aac files

`https://dve-streams.akamaized.net/ads-1/ns-004/MjAyMA/OQ/OA/509dfa9e-8c13-4e95-81dd-9ef4d27af7ca/audio/4d8cfd0d-26b2-4869-8c5a-488199003c95/1.aac?hdntl=exp=1638041076~acl=/*~id=77f74994-2e71-474c-93ae-fa06e58a850f~data=hdntl~hmac=e37b7c6b297c9a86c98528404edbafd448addbacc327eaf5d6117082af5b63e0`

---

Once you have all .aac files, create a text file of segments listed in order.

```
1.aac
2.aac
3.aac
...
```

Make sure there's no blank line at the end, and then

```
ffmpeg -i "concatf:list.txt" -c copy out.m4a
```

`concatf` was added in July 2021, so you will need a recent git master build.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, Actually I've made a mistake as you suggest to download them as `aac`, (_the browser by default downloads them as .mp3_), then I manually renamed the extension to `aac`. After a lot of try-errors, I realized that the download segments have incorrect duration and need to used the command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084389/6142097  (`ffmpeg.exe -i .\data\4.aac .\data\4.mp3`) to fix it. But why to convert to `mp3` when they're already downloaded as `mp3`. No need to rename to `aac`. Finally the output format should be the same: `output.mp3`

Comment: `ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i .\data\list.txt .\data\output.mp3` worked without any filters or other arguments.